# Loop Over Pelican MetaData Returns Null

Tags: for-loop, jinja2, pelican, static-site

I am trying to generate `list items` for creating a list of `musicians` who donate to the current "active" `charity` page.

**charity-test.md:**

```
Title: Charity Test
Category: charities
Template: charity
```

**musician-test.md**

```
Title: Some Musician
Category: musicians
Template: musician
Charities: Charity Test
```

**charity.html** (template):

```twig
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
{% include 'parts/common/header-common.html' %}

{{ article.content }}

<h3>Donations made to {{ article.title }} by&colon;</h3>
<ul>
{% for charity, articles in charities|sort %}
    {% if charity == article.title %}
    <li><a href="/{{ charity.url }}">{{ charity.title }}</a> ({{ categories|count }}) </li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>

{% endblock content %}
```

**Should return:**

```html
<h3>Donations made to Charity Test by&colon;</h3>
<ul>
    <li><a href="/some-musician.html">Some Musician</a>(1)</li>
</ul>
```

**But I get:**

```html
<h3>Donations made to Charity Test by&colon;</h3>
<ul>
  </ul>
```

I have also tried using the 'categories' route without luck. I cannot seem to get my head around this one. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered that Pelican is limited out-of-the-box with it's abilities and this is not possible w/o writing a plugin to support this loop.